# Tokensregex rules to identify quantities not working correctly

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I'm encountering a strange problem. I am using **Tokensregex** to identify Quantities from text and for the most part it's working well, however, in the sentence given below it **fails to identify 1.2 million** as a quantity whereas the same rule **works for 2.4 million**. I've tried everything..I'm a little stumped.

Anyone got any clue as to why one quantity gets identified while the other does not? Could this be in some way dependent on the phrase POS tags? The word POS tags in both cases are CD but their phrase tags differe. In one case the it is QP (for 1.2 million) and in another ADJP.

> **Sentence:** The No. 3 vehicle seller in the United States behind General
>   Motors Co (GM.N) and Ford Motor Co (F.N), Toyota imports 1.2 million
>   vehicles to the U.S. market annually, half of its 2.4 million U.S.
>   sales

**Rules:**

```
 {
    ruleType: "tokens",
    pattern: ((($QUANTITY_NAME)*?([{pos: CD}]+)?($QUANTITY_NAME)?)),
    action: Annotate($1,ner,"QUANTITY"),
    result: "QUANTITY"

 }

  {
    ruleType: "tokens",
    pattern: (([{pos: CD}]+)?),
    action: Annotate($1,ner,"QUANTITY"),
    result: "QUANTITY"

 }
```

**POS Tags:**

```
(ROOT (NP (NP (DT The) (NN No.) (CD 3) (NN vehicle) (NN seller)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NP (DT the) (NNP United) (NNPS States)) (PP (IN behind) (NP (NP (NNP General) (NNPS Motors) (NNP Co)) (PRN (-LRB- -LRB-) (NP (NNP GM.N)) (-RRB- -RRB-)) (CC and) (NP (NNP Ford) (NNP Motor) (NNP Co)) (PRN (-LRB- -LRB-) (NP (NNP F.N)) (-RRB- -RRB-)))))) (, ,) (NP (NP (NNP Toyota) (NNS imports)) (NP (NP (QP (CD 1.2) (CD million)) (NNS vehicles)) (TO to) (NP (NP (DT the) (NNP U.S.) (NN market)) (ADVP (RB annually))))) (, ,) (NP (NP (NN half)) (PP (IN of) (NP (PRP$ its) (ADJP (CD 2.4) (CD million)) (NNP U.S.) (NNS sales)))) (. .)))
```

Comment: Looks weird at first sight indeed. Could you include the code you're using to get the output? Have you tried reversing the order of the amounts, i.e. as input: "Toyota imports 2.4 million vehicles to the U.S. market annually, half of its 1.2 million U.S. sales". Not sure if the TokensRegex module is POS-tag or position-informed (I would think not). Seeing the actual code you are using could help in finding potential mistakes.